# Setting package path in Go

Tags: go

Getting started with Go and going through the docs here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

The part entitled **Package paths** recommends using my Github account as a base path. However, with the forward slashes in the GH url, when I run `mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/user` it creates a sub-folder. So the example of `github.com/user` creates:

```
src/
    github.com/
        user/
```

but I don't think this is what's intended.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually the intended behavior,

You can even call `go get` on a github repo and it will create this same directory structure

Comment: Oh right - I don't think the example directory structure makes this clear but thanks

Answer (score 6):

The behavior is correct. The packages names in Go provide unique global name space.

`github.com/user/repo` therefore identifies a package, which is easily `go get` -able (download and install the package) and also provides much needed separation. You can also create packages without a hostname (in this case github.com) but effectively preventing users from using `go get` and resorting to manual management.

Having a username in GitHub case allows you to use forks of other libraries and maintain the separation. The full package name is then used for importing

```
import "github.com/user/repo"
```